# Internal microphone not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a laptop running 18.04 with a `Realtek ALC269VC` card and `Pulseaudio`. The speakers are working normally. Same when plugging headphones. But the internal microphone is not. No sound is produced although I see the bar here going somehow back and forth.

[image: Micrphone level moving]

Alsamixer configuration seems fine.

[image: Alsa mixer conf]

Already tried purging `pulseaudio` and `alsa-base` but no improvement. What could be the issue ? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, only worse:my system (Kubutu 18.04) now doesn't even recognize the existence of any sound input devices.  Needless to say, it wasn't this way until recently.  My advice: be very wary of purging any sound-related modules such as pulseaudio.  You may be destroying a lot more stuff than you bargained for.